# Customized html not parsed correctly in DocuSign email template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docusignapi, digital-signature, docusigncompositetmplts

I am using DocuSign in my web application for signing a document digitally. I do some customization in email templates of my DocuSign demo account for more user friendly email contents. Please see the below code for see customization code.

[image]

This code work fine till yesterday. But now I found a issue about email template like below image.

[image]

email string is not parsed correctly in `DocuSign`. I am clueless about this issue.

Comment: I don't know who is down voted this question. Actually this issue realted to DocuSign team... Please explain what is the reason to give down vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an account setting that needs to be toggled on your account called `Allow HTML input in the API`, please contact your DocuSign Account Manager or DocuSign Support to enable this setting in your account.

Comment: I already contacted the DocuSign support team, and now it's solved.